# PDF Accessibility Issue With Color Contrast

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, accessibility

When I run the Full Check within Adobe Pro, and get a list of things to fix within Accessibility Checker, one of the issues I've been having is "Color Contrast - Needs manual check"

Problem is that I do what is required to fix it, ie, go to Edit > Preference, Click on Accessibility, Select "Replace Document Colors", and then select "Use High-Contrast Colors", and then click "Ok".

Then I go back to the document itself, and pass it manually since that's the only way to "pass" it.

When I close the document, and open it again, and run the Full Check again, this pops up again and again. No matter what I do, or the settings I choose, the passing it manually doesn't seem to save it, and that bothers me.

How do I get the pass manually saved within the document so it doesn't keep popping up each time?

To clarify exactly what I'm doing here, here are two links to give context: 
https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/create-verify-pdf-accessibility.html?trackingid=KACNN#ColorContrast and https://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/acrobat/using-acrobat-pro-accessibility-checker.html

Any advice to save the Color Contrast when passed manually?

**EDIT**

If it helps, this link explains much quicker what I'm trying to do here: https://it.cornell.edu/accessibility/color-contrast

Use High Contrast Colors in Acrobat

Under Preferences, select Accessibility.

Select Replace Document Colors.

Select Use High Contrast Colors.

Select Change the color of line art as well as text.

Select OK.

It's once I've selected 'OK' and close the document, and then reopen it to check the settings, that I see that it still needs to be manually checked. That is what's puzzling me, i.e., why it won't stay saved so to speak.